# Standards on new API version

Tags: api, rest, standards

We have solution based product which expose the rest API and our product has quarterly releases. Also, we expose an API for all the functionality we do in UI, and it may by around 30 end point.

Current we are exposing the API as v1.0 for first release planned on this Month.

My Question regarding this API versioning are,

1. Do we need to increase an API version whenever there is new set of API released?
2. Do we need to  support all old API in new version if new version get release?
   Ex: We have AddUser API in v1.0, if we release AddUserWithoutEmail API in v2.0  then Do we need allow AddUser API in v2.0

I am aware that there is many Q&A available on this topic but I didn’t get what I am exactly looking for so I have created this one.